# How do I send an arbitrary command to Redis with the ServiceStack.Redis client?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

Redis [security best practices](http://redis.io/topics/security) recommend renaming commands in order to suppress unauthorized/unintended execution.  *What's the best way to issue an arbitrary (renamed) command with the ServiceStack.Redis client?*

**What We've Tried So Far:** We've renamed the *PUBLISH* command to *HSILBUP*.  I've attempted to use the following code block to issue a *HSILBUP* command.  This results in a null reference exception when `FlushSendBuffer` is called.  I'm using these methods because their names suggest the behavior I want. I have no idea if this is their intended function.

```
var command = new[]
{
    ToByteArray("HSILBUP"),
    ToByteArray("channel"),
    ToByteArray("message")
};

redisClient.WriteAllToSendBuffer(command);
redisClient.FlushSendBuffer();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest change is to make the change directly in the ServiceStack.Redis project code.  You'll want to change Commands.cs

Change this from:

```
public readonly static byte[] Publish = "PUBLISH".ToUtf8Bytes();
```

to:

```
public readonly static byte[] Publish = "HSILBUP".ToUtf8Bytes();
```